# Enviar mail en app sintra ruby

Tags: html, ruby

Bueno tengo el siguiente formulario en mi vista de index

```
<form action="/mailcontacto" method="post">
            <div class="jx-ticket-first-name">
            <input type="text" id="reg_name" name="reg_name" placeholder="Nombre" class="jx-form-text" />
            </div>
        <div class="jx-ticket-phone">
        <input type="text" id="reg_empresa" name="reg_empresa" placeholder="Institución" class="jx-form-text" />
        </div>
            <div class="jx-ticket-email">
            <input type="text" id="reg_email" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email" class="jx-form-text" data-validation-length="email" data-validation="required"/>
            </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="reg_subject" name="reg_subject" placeholder="Número Telefónico" class="jx-form-text" />
            <div class="jx-ticket-phone">
            <input type="text" id="reg_phone" name="reg_phone" placeholder="Número Telefónico" class="jx-form-text" />
            </div>
        <div class="jx-ticket-phone">
            <input type="text" id="reg_mensaje" name="reg_mensaje" placeholder="Mensaje" class="jx-form-text" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit-register-9" name="submit-register-9" class="jx-form-btn jx-btn-default" value="send" placeholder="Enviar" />
            </form>
```

El cual me envía a la vista /es/mail contacto que tengo creado en mi app.rb (principal) el cual lo definí como sigue:

```
post '/es/mailcontacto' do
  require 'pony'

  from = "info@actuarialanalytics.com.mx"
  subject = "Solicitud de información o demo"

  Pony.mail(
    :from => from,
    :subject => subject,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' },
    :body => erb(:"/mail"),
    :to => 'para',
    :via => :smtp,
    :via_options => {
    :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port                 => '587',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name            => 'usuario',
    :password             => 'contraseña',
    :authentication       => :plain, # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
    :domain               => "dominio"
      })
  redirect '/'
end
```

Entonces el cuerpo del mail lo tengo en otra vista en donde llamo a los valores del formulario la cual se llama mail.erb  y contiene lo siguiente:

```
<p><%= "Nombre: #{params[:reg_name]}" %></p>
<p><%= "Emepresa: #{params[:reg_empresa]}" %></p>
<p><%= "Email: #{params[:reg_email]}" %></p>
<p><%= "Telefono: #{params[:reg_phone]}" %></p>
<p><%= "Asunto: #{params[:reg_subject]}" %></p>
<p><%= "Mensaje: #{params[:reg_mesaje]}" %></p>
```

Por lo que entiendo del error es que cuando le pico al botón enviar no me envía realmente a la vista es/mailcontacto, me marca un error de Internal Server, no logro decifrar que es lo que pasa, no le se mucho a sinatra, espero que alguien pudiera ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que muestra el servidor?

Comment: También muestra el formulario completo.

Comment: El error solo me dice "Internal Server Error" en una página blanca, o sea me envía a la vista localhost:3003/es/mailcontacto y esa vista dice "Internal Server Error"

Comment: ¿Cómo estás ejecutando la aplicación? En la ventana de terminal donde ejecutas `ruby app.rb` debería aparecerte el error que genera el servidor.

Comment: Hoy voy revisar bien, ya le había checado ahí pero no me marcaba ningún error

Comment: Ya vi bien, hay un error, creo que es en la configuración en el app.rb

Comment: 2017-08-22 18:39:44 - Net::SMTPAuthenticationError - 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsf

Answer (score 0):

1. Verifica que tengas los permisos en google para poder enviar los correos desde tu aplicación (puedes hacerlo en [este enlace](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)).
2. Cambia el valor de `:authentication` por `:login`:

```
:authentication => :login
```

Comment: Ya lo intente, cambiando el login y activando el permiso en la página que me dices, pero me sale el mismo error y me dice que para más información vaya aquí https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuw pero no me dice nada ese link

Comment: @JerryJiménez ¿El error sigue siendo el mismo?, ¿podrías agregar el log completo a tu pregunta?

Comment: Ya pude solucionar el error, es decir, en mis 2 fomularios ya puedo enviar los mails, tenía que autorizar algo en gmail, ahora el problema esque solo funciona localmente, cuando lo cargo a una app de heroku me marca error de nuevo -.-